# How can I get shell command output to line up?

Tags: ruby, bash, shell

I'm writing a utility method in Ruby to run shell commands on a remote server.

Here's what I have so far...

```
def exec_remotely(command)
  remote_command = "ssh -t #{@config['remote_username']}@#{@config['target_server']} '#{command}'"
  puts "------> Executing:"
  puts "        #{remote_command}"
  output = `#{remote_command}`
  output.lines.each do |line|
    puts "        #{line}"
  end
end
```

The effect I want on the console is this:

```
------> Executing:
        ssh -t user@host.com 'ls -alh'
        Connection to host.com closed.
        total 8.7M
        drwx------ 10 username username 4.0K Sep  5 18:11 .
        drwxr-xr-x  3 root  root  4.0K Aug 26 21:18 ..
        -rw-------  1 username username 1.6K Sep  5 17:47 .bash_history
        -rw-r--r--  1 username username   18 Dec  2  2011 .bash_logout
        -rw-r--r--  1 username username   48 Aug 27 02:52 .bash_profile
        -rw-r--r--  1 username username  353 Aug 27 03:05 .bashrc

        # etc...
```

But what I'm getting instead is this...

```
------> Executing:
        ssh -t user@host.com 'ls -alh'
Connection to host.com closed.
        total 8.7M
        drwx------ 10 username username 4.0K Sep  5 18:11 .
        drwxr-xr-x  3 root  root  4.0K Aug 26 21:18 ..
        -rw-------  1 username username 1.6K Sep  5 17:47 .bash_history
        -rw-r--r--  1 username username   18 Dec  2  2011 .bash_logout
        -rw-r--r--  1 username username   48 Aug 27 02:52 .bash_profile
        -rw-r--r--  1 username username  353 Aug 27 03:05 .bashrc

        # etc...
```

How can I get everything to line up vertically? (Except for the "------>". That's supposed to start at the left edge.)

Comment: With backticks you catch stdout, not stderr. Perhaps `popen3` helps you -> http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html

Comment: You could bind *STDERR* to *STDOUT* running `ssh 2>&1 -t ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it the way you're going about it. `Connection to host.com closed.` is output by the command you called, and not returned via STDOUT, which you could capture with backticks.

The problem is the use of backticks. They don't capture STDERR, which is most likely what ssh is using when it outputs its status.

The fix is to use Open3's methods, such as [`capture3`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-capture3) which will grab the STDOUT and STDERR streams returned by the called program, and let you output them programmatically, allowing you to align them:

```
stdout_str, stderr_str, status = Open3.capture3([env,] cmd... [, opts])
```

You should also look at Ruby's [`printf`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/ARGF.html#method-i-printf), [`sprintf`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) or String's [`%`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-25) method, which calls `sprintf`. Using `%` you can easily format your strings to align:

```
format = '%7s %s'
puts format % ["------>", "Executing:"]
puts format % ["", remote_command]
output = `#{remote_command}`
output.lines.each do |line|
  puts format % ["", line]
end
```

Combine that with the code to use `capture3` and you should be where you want to be.